# "Request body" doesn't appears on Swagger UI

Tags: node.js, swagger, openapi

I'm trying to do a test with a **POST** request on my Swagger Documentation, but I'm having the following trouble:

On Swagger Editor I can test it normally, but on Swagger UI the Request body field doesn't appears, so I can't put my email and password to test the request.

Here you can see the Request body field with data examples ready to be edited:
[Swagger Editor Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImMqt.png)

And here you can see that Swagger UI doesn't shows it:
[Swagger UI Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6NpK.png)

Note: I've generated a **nodejs-server**.

My `.yaml` code:

```
openapi: '3.0.1'

info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Test
  description: Test openapi.

servers:
  - url: http://localhost:3005

paths:
  /login:
    post:
      summary: Login
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/login'
      responses:
        200:
          description: Test

components:
  schemas:
    login:
      type: object
      properties:
        email:
          type: string
          example: example@example.com.br
        password:
          type: string
          format: password
          example: example123
        expires:
          type: integer
          example: 86400
      required:
       - email
       - password
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: Update Swagger UI to the latest version.**

Just to clarify the scenario (for future readers): The OP pasted this OpenAPI 3.0 definition into Swagger Editor, generated a Node.js server and ran it. The request body display issue is with Swagger UI that is part of this Node.js server (`http://localhost:8080/docs`).

The issue is that this Node.js server uses a very old version of Swagger UI. More specifically, it uses the 
[`oas3-tools`](https://github.com/bug-hunters/oas3-tools) package v. 1.0.1, which has Swagger UI v. 3.3.1 bundled with it. The latest Swagger UI version (as of this writing) is 3.22.1, and it does not have the described issue.

The solution is to update Swagger UI to the latest version:

- There's an [existing issue](https://github.com/bug-hunters/oas3-tools/issues/11) in the `oas3-tools` repository to update the bundled Swagger UI to the latest version. Consider submitting a PR to fix this.
- As a quick fix, you can fork `oas3-tools`, update the bundled Swagger UI files in the `<oas3-tools>\middleware\swagger-ui` folder, and then update the `package.json` of the generated Node.js server to refer to your `oas3-tools` fork instead.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand how to update Swagger UI. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Although the 'request body' field does show up in the UI with the suggested update by [@Helen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55806780/5657159), the posted body object still seems to fail to show up in the controller, probably since the bundled swagger-tools middleware is old as well. I had to make a few changes to **node_modules/oas3-tools/middleware/swagger-metada.js** for the requestBody to show up on req.swagger.params in the controller. I hope this can help to get a project through while an official [oas3-tools](https://github.com/bug-hunters/oas3-tools) code is in the works (if at all).

Line 162, after `var parsers = _.reduce(parameters ... }, [])` block:

```
if (swaggerMetadata.operation.requestBody && parsers.indexOf(bodyParser) === -1) parsers.push(bodyParser);
```

Line 225 after `_.each(parameters, ... });` block:

```
if (req.body) swaggerMetadata.params.body = {value: req.body};
```

Comment: Which file did you make this change?

Comment: To the swagger-metada.js under oas3-tools/middleware/.