# Open API 3.0 - Request body is not shown in swagger documentation page

Tags: node.js, swagger, openapi

I am playing around with Open API 3.0 by downloading the source code for server, [here](https://editor.swagger.io/).

- Access the link
- Choose **Generate Server** on menu bar
- Choose **nodejs-server**

I simply follow the instruction in `README.md` to run the server by executing `npm start`.

After that, I access the URL http://localhost:8080/docs. However, there is no **Request body** in the swagger page. More specifically, you can see in the picture as following

[image]

The code in `yaml` file for this api as following

```
/pet:
  put:
    tags:
    - pet
    summary: Update an existing pet
    operationId: updatePet
    requestBody:
      description: Pet object that needs to be added to the store
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
        application/xml:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
      required: true
    responses:
      "400":
        description: Invalid ID supplied
        content: {}
      "404":
        description: Pet not found
        content: {}
      "405":
        description: Validation exception
        content: {}
    security:
    - petstore_auth:
      - write:pets
      - read:pets
    x-codegen-request-body-name: body
    x-swagger-router-controller: Pet
```

On the other hand, the things showed in https://editor.swagger.io/ are somehow different, but `yaml` file is exactly the same.

[image]
How can I make the swagger on my local machine show **Request body** as in https://editor.swagger.io/?

Comment: Your local Swagger UI version is probably outdated. To learn what version you use, open the browser dev tools > Console tab and evaluate `versions`. The latest version is 3.24.3; if yours is older you'll most likely need to update it.

Comment: Hi @Helen, you are right! The problem is solved!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“Request body” doesn't appears on Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55806780/113116)

Comment: Hi @Helen, actually I just tried using `swagger-ui-express` instead of `oas3-tools` to solve the problem. I also check the swagger ui version for `swagger-ui-express` as you suggested by `JSON.stringify(versions);` in browser dev tools that shown `{"swaggerUi":{"version":"3.24.3",...}}`. The question is: Should I use `oas3-tools` or `swagger-ui-express`?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not really familiar with any of those libraries.